# AttributeError while trying to use threading with the mss library

Tags: python, multithreading, screen-capture

I'm trying to write a simple class to use image detection in multithreading.
But getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 
  1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 
  975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "e:\Dev\CV3\vision.py", line 19, in image_tracker
    img = np.asarray(self.stc.grab(coordinates))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Dev\CV3\venv\Lib\site-packages\mss\base.py", line 
  90, in grab
    screenshot = self._grab_impl(monitor)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Dev\CV3\venv\Lib\site-packages\mss\windows.py", line 
  235, in _grab_impl
    srcdc, memdc = self._handles.srcdc, self._handles.memdc
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'srcdc'
(venv)
```

my vision.py is:

```
import cv2
import mss
import numpy as np


class Vision:

stc = mss.mss()

def __init__(self, mon,):

    self.mon = self.stc.monitors[mon]

def image_tracker(self, top, left, width, height, window_name):

    coordinates = {'top': self.mon['top'] + top, 'left': self.mon['left'] + left, 'width': width, 'height': height}

    while True:
        img = np.asarray(self.stc.grab(coordinates))
        cv2.imshow(f'{window_name}', img)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

main.py:

```
from vision import Vision
from threading import Thread


vision = Vision(2)

tensinon_line = Thread(target=vision.image_tracker, args=(1340, 870, 300, 25, 'Tension',))
counter = Thread(target=vision.image_tracker, args=(1300, 1385, 27, 20, 'Counter',))

tensinon_line.start()
counter.start()
```

It'seems that "srcdc" is some `mss` var which in not creating in thread but I can't get how to fix it...

Comment: @Alexander I've edited the main post and added the full traceback. But actually, I can't even start only one thread

Comment: Does any of the code work *without* threading? For example, can you call the `image_tracker` method directly? Also: why is there a class in this code, if you are only going to create one instance and reuse it (even across multiple threads) and have the instance use class-shared data (`stc`, which is not created per-instance)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, it works perfectly without threading, but I can't using it without... cuz I need doint some acts depending on state of some parametrs which can changing in time

Comment: @KarlKnechtel should I just add stc in method image_tracker ?

Comment: upd. Yes, now it works! But what is the right architecture for my desicion ? I need 5 windows for tracking some changing on my screen and doing some things at the same time, (for examle sending messange in messengers without stopping tracking)

Comment: **not** OpenCV issue. it's an `mss` issue. I have no idea how you could have concluded otherwise, from the traceback pointing to source files that relate to `mss`

Answer (score 1):

The way you instantiate MSS is problematic. It is created by the main thread, and then you are trying to use it from sub-threads. That won't work since MSS v8.0.

What you can do is to do the instantiation into the class:

```py
class Vision:

  def __init__(self, mon,):
    self.sct = mss.mss()
    self.mon = self.sct.monitors[mon]

    def image_tracker(self, top, left, width, height, window_name):
        coordinates = {'top': self.mon['top'] + top, 'left': self.mon['left'] + left, 'width': width, 'height': height}

        while True:
            img = np.asarray(self.sct.grab(coordinates))
            cv2.imshow(f'{window_name}', img)

            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```